# How do I fix the 'Only "Solidity" or "Yul" is supported as a language' error from py-solc-x

Tags: solidity, solc, py-solc-x

this is the error I get after running this code

```py
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

install_solc("0.6.0")

#from my crowdFund.sol file i call the whole file
with open("./CrowdFund.sol", "r") as file:
    FromOld = file.read()


#compile our solidity


compiled_Sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "solidity",
        "sources": {"CrowdFund.sol": {"content":FromOld}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*":["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)
print("compiled_Sol")
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SpiderHunter\Desktop\Solidity_Pro\deploy.py", line 13, in <module>
    compiled_Sol = compile_standard(
  File "C:\Users\SpiderHunter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 394, in compile_standard
    raise SolcError(
solcx.exceptions.SolcError: Only "Solidity" or "Yul" is supported as a language.
> command: `C:\Users\SpiderHunter\.solcx\solc-v0.6.0\solc.exe --standard-json`
> return code: `0`
> stdout:
{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"Only \"Solidity\" or \"Yul\" is supported as a language.","message":"Only \"Solidity\" or \"Yul\" is supported as a language.","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}

> stderr:
```

Answer (score 2):

For `language` you used a lower-case `solidity`, but it is required to be exactly `Solidity`.

Here the official docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/using-the-compiler.html#input-description

Here an js example for an input: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/186a21a74b327f17fc41217a927dea7064f74604/test/utils/setup.ts#L99